# Why does Zotero for Word 2007 output APA with the first name, only on existing docs?

Tags: microsoft-word, firefox-extensions, microsoft-word-2007, bibliography, zotero

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/02/ says that single-author publications at the end of a paragraph should look like this:

> (Tremblay, 2012)

A fresh install of Zotero for Firefox and the corresponding Word plugin (the whose Document Preferences say APA 6th edition) produce inline citations in a preexisting non-Zotero'd document like this:

> (Valérie Tremblay, 2012)

In a brand new document, like this (correct):

> (Tremblay, 2012)

Ruled out:

1. Unlike the suggestion at http://libraryguides.missouri.edu/c.php?g=27928&p=172245 there is only one entry with that name in my Zotero database, and the trash is even empty.  In fact, it's the only entry, period.
2. Another place suggested it might be related to the Firefox plugin having the author's name in "single field" mode (at least for the first output above).  It's not (as you can probably infer from the second output above).

If it were some obscure format I might be less puzzled, but it's APA...they must be one of the top three standards, right?  How can this be fixed?  Why does it only affect existing documents?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Word addon's "Remove field codes", then re-add references.  Now it works.